# Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I run `npm start` in powershell is shows the following error error:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\UTKARSH\Desktop\react_native\my_project> npm start
>
> @ start C:\Users\UTKARSH\Desktop\react_native\my_project
> expo start
>
> Starting project at C:\Users\UTKARSH\Desktop\react_native\my_project
> Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
> ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
>     at Object.getExpoSDKVersion (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Project.ts:22:9)
>     at ensureConfigHasDefaultValues (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:419:22)
>     at fillAndReturnConfig (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:101:10)
>     at getConfig (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\config\src\Config.ts:137:10)
>     at configureProjectAsync (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:288:25)
>     at action (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:164:34)
>     at C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:341:16
>     at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:82:7)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\UTKARSH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-15T07_09_48_901Z-debug.log
> PS C:\Users\UTKARSH\Desktop\react_native\my_project> clear
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did u install expo-cli? are u even using expo? or is it just react native?

Comment: @yesIamFaded React Native. Because the path says  ...\react_native\...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem. I solved it like this:

I was using old Node version with NVM. I changed to the last node version

```
nvm use 12.x.x
```

with `nvm` and updated:

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

but, you need run

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

for `npm`. After that, I changed back to the old version:

```
nvm use 10.x.x
```

and ran

```
yarn start
```

or

```
npm start
```

This solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem. I installed yarn and then ran the command "yarn add expo".

Answer (score -1):

to solve the above issue first, go to your folder to type "cd projectname" then enter , and now run "npx expo start" command